# Why converting char to int using ASCI is faster than parsing a char using int.parse()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, casting, time-complexity

Both of these code blocks calculate how many times needed to sum a number digits till it becomes only one digit.

I don't know why the second way is much faster than the first, my assumptions are it may be related to the way that char is converted to int or the subtract() with huge numbers, but I still don't know why!

```
//First Way
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            BigInteger currentNumberValue = BigInteger.Parse(number);
            int timesOfSpells = 0;
            BigInteger sum = 0;

            while (currentNumberValue >= 10)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < currentNumberValue.ToString().Length; i++)
                {
                    BigInteger currentNumber = 
                    int.Parse(currentNumberValue.ToString().Substring(i, 1));

                    sum += currentNumber;
                }
                currentNumberValue = sum;
                sum = 0;
                timesOfSpells++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(timesOfSpells);
```

```
//Second Way
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            int numberLength = number.Length;

            int numberOfSpells = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberLength; i++)
            {
                BigInteger sum = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
                {
                    char o = number[j];
                    int b = o - '0';

                    sum += b;
                }

                if (sum !=0 && number.Length !=1)
                    numberOfSpells++;

                number = sum.ToString();

                if (number.Length == 1)
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(numberOfSpells);
```

Comment: A `char` is stored as an `int` (which is why you can perform add/subtract operations).  So in that case there is no need to do any conversions, it's a straight mathematical operation.  Your second case requires converting to string, getting a sub string then converting back to an int.  Obviously many more steps there.

Comment: How often are you running this that it matters?

Comment: Thanks Mike, my thoughts were that although the first way has more steps it may not be the only reason for the huge difference in execution time between the two ways, I think there is a specific operation that causes the bad performance.

Comment: Calling BigInteger.ToString as the loop condition probably has ramifications. Cache it in a variable first. Converting back and forth between int/BigInteger has some overhead as well. You should probably use BigInteger.Parse in the loop similar to the second line

Comment: @MikeH How can you say char is stored as an int? while a char takes 1 byte in memory and an int takes 4?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran, a char is stored as a 16 bit unsigned integer. So, it's more akin to a `ushort` than `int`.  I should have been more precise and said that a char is an integral type, not specifically an int.  The point was that because it's an integral type arithmetic operations can be performed very quickly.